# how to prevent downloading image again

Tags: flutter

Hello i trying to download and share image and product information i am using imagepicker saver and esys packages i was wondering if i could prevent the download of an image twice.How do i achieve that.

custom button based on platform

```
AppButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  isIOS: isIOS,
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,
                  icon: FrinoIcons.f_share,
                  buttonType: ButtonType.Resell,
                  text: 'Share Product',
                  onPressed: () => onImageDownLoad(product),
                )
```

//function

```
void onImageDownLoad(Product product) async {
      List list = [];
      final String text = "${product.name}\n\n${product.description}";
      var req = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(product.image[0]));
      var response = await req.close();
      Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
      if (list.length == 0) {
        list.add(File.fromRawPath(bytes));
        await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: bytes).whenComplete(() {
          EsysShare.Share.file('ESYS AMLOG', 'amlog.jpg', bytes, 'image/jpg',
              text: text);
        });
      } else {
        for (Uint8List items in list) {
          print(list);
          if (items == bytes) {
            EsysShare.Share.file('ESYS AMLOG', 'amlog.jpg', items, 'image/jpg',
                text: text);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you share the code calling the above function ?

Comment: Where is downloaded twice? You mean if the user press the same button again?

Comment: No if the image is downloaded use that image if not download the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare the list globally

```
List list = [];

void onImageDownLoad(Product product) async {
           final String text = "${product.name}\n\n${product.description}";
      var req = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(product.image[0]));
      var response = await req.close();
      Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
      if (list.length == 0) {
        list.add(File.fromRawPath(bytes));
        await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: bytes).whenComplete(() {
          EsysShare.Share.file('ESYS AMLOG', 'amlog.jpg', bytes, 'image/jpg',
              text: text);
        });
      } else {
        for (Uint8List items in list) {
          print(list);
          if (items == bytes) {
            EsysShare.Share.file('ESYS AMLOG', 'amlog.jpg', items, 'image/jpg',
                text: text);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: let me know if this helps